# How to hide the keyboard clipboard programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

Everytime I click UItextview this clipboard would appear on the bottom, how can I disable it programmatically?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBzBc.png)

Comment: You should try this one.: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115445

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On **iPhone** you could just set **autocorrectionType = .no** to completely remove that bar above the keyboard.

On **iPad** however you should first add these extensions:

```
extension UITextView {
    func hideSuggestions() {
        // Removes suggestions only
        autocorrectionType = .no
        //Removes Undo, Redo, Copy & Paste options
        removeUndoRedoOptions()
    }
}

extension UITextField {
    func hideSuggestions() {
        // Removes suggestions only
        autocorrectionType = .no
        //Removes Undo, Redo, Copy & Paste options
        removeUndoRedoOptions()
    }
}

extension UIResponder {
    func removeUndoRedoOptions() {
        //Removes Undo, Redo, Copy & Paste options
        inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
        inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
    }
}
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

1. **To just remove the Undo, Redo, Copy and Paste options** but show suggestions on top of keyboard, **call the function func removeUndoRedoOptions()**
   [image: After]
2. **To completely remove the suggestion bar along with Undo, Redo, Copy and Paste options, call the function func hideSuggestions()**
   [image: After]

Comment: You are welcome, if it helped you I would really appreciate if you select this as the accepted answer for others who might come across this question. :)

Comment: Hi, I have another question. I am using unbutton for uitextview input, is there anyways that I can hide the virtual keyboard when editing uitextview?

Comment: Hi! Yes, when you are done writing and press your UIButton, you could just call myTextField.resignFirstResponder() to hide the keyboard.

Additionally, if you don't want the keyboard to appear and/or want any other action when the user taps, set myTextField.delegate = self and on UITextField delegate
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        switch textField {
        case myTextField:
            return false 
            default:
            return true
        }
}

Comment: Thank you Nick, then please don't forget to set this answer as selected. Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

You can disable your textView user interaction:

```
yourTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

or you can disable textView editability

```
yourTextView.isEditable = false
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to make cursor appears, but do not want this clipboard appears set your textView to become first responder and set your textView inputView with a blank UIView():

```
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

after that set your textView inputView with a blank UIView():

```
textView.inputView = UIView()
```

Comment: I want to make cursor appears, but do not want this clipboard appears.

Comment: add this: yourTextView.becomeFirstResponder() and after that add this: yourTextView.inputView = UIView()

Comment: Hi, I have another question. I am using unbutton for uitextview input, is there anyways that I can hide the virtual keyboard when editing uitextview?